# How to stop Stream when switching between tabs of CupertinoTabBar

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have 3 BottomNavigationBarItem , in one of them I have a stream called in StreamBuilder, its work fine, but when I switching between tabs it does not dispose,

how can I dispose StreamBuilber when Im switching tab.

Nb: when switching tabs, @disponse is not called

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're switching tabs you must be managing **index** of current selected tab. Use ternary if else right before your StreamBuilder like this and replace it with empty Container.

```
child: _tabIndex == 0 ?  StreamBuilder(....) : Container(),
```